# Django prefetch_select and reverse join issue

Tags: python, django, orm

I am working on multiple join with Django.

```
questions = Question.objects.select_related(
    'publishedquestionmapping__library_question'
).prefetch_related(
    'publishedquestionmapping__library_question__contributor_set__user', 
).filter(
    hide=False).order_by('-pub_date')[:count]

for question in questions:
    contributers = question.publishedquestionmapping.library_question.contributor_set.all() 
    for contributer in contributers:
        print contributer.user
```

The Error is `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Contributor has no user.`

The problem is that I can use prefetch_related
`...contributor_set__user`, but I can't use contributer.user?

btw, `print contributer.user_id` is ok.

This Model Contributer

```
class Contributor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

I want to do like `contributer.user.username`. How should I do that?!

Thanks!

Comment: Try printing the object attributes to check its relations `print dir(contributer )`

Comment: It's like ```[...'full_clean', 'get_deferred_fields', 'id', 'objects', 'pk', 'prepare_database_save', 'question', 'question_id', 'refresh_from_db', 'save', 'save_base', 'serializable_value', 'unique_error_message', 'user', 'user_id', 'validate_unique']
```

Comment: can you try to run your code with `print getattr(contributer, 'user', None)`? instead of `contributer.user`

Comment: it prints None.